# Python function inside function needs paramter from outer function

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm currently programming a alarm.

```
def alarm_checker(event_date_list, alarm_triggered):
    while True:
            time_now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
            time_now = datetime.strptime(time_now, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
            time.sleep(1)
            for i in event_date_list:
                if time_now == i[3]:
                    i[3] = i[3].strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
                    alarm_triggered(i)


def alarm_triggered(i):
     print("Alarm successfully triggered" + i)


def main():
     alarm_checker(test_event_list, alarm_triggered(i=))
```

As you can see in the code above, I compare the times of the list `event_date_list` with the current time I get from `time_now`. When the two times are the same, I want to execute the function `alarm_triggered`, just as written in the arguments of `alarm_checker`. As I need to check which time in the list triggered everything, I decided to pass the `alarm_triggered` function the argument `i`.

My question is though, what should I write as the argument for `i` in `alarm_checker` in my main function? I only get the value of `i` when `alarm_checker` is already running, so what should I write for the start?

I already tried to make `i` an empty string, but then I get the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` upon executing the program.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You are actually calling your function, which returns `None` and attempting to call that. You should not call your function. You meant to write: `alarm_checker(test_event_list, alarm_triggered)`

Comment: Also, unless you intend to pass in a different function other than `alarm_triggered`, you can just remove that parameter from `alarm_checker` and the call site and it will still work.